# using lead or lag from dplyr in combination with other variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe:

```
                 Time   CardID    Data      Type
1  2018-01-01 10:44:35 10037479 PowerOn  STBEvent
2  2018-01-01 10:44:48 10037479    0401 UseRemote
3  2018-01-01 10:44:53 10037479    0301 UseRemote
4  2018-01-01 10:45:13 10037479    0401 UseRemote
5  2018-01-01 10:45:24 10037479    0301 UseRemote
6  2018-01-01 10:45:30 10037479    1415  LiveView
7  2018-01-01 10:45:37 10037479    0401 UseRemote
8  2018-01-01 11:08:01 10037479    1412  LiveView
9  2018-01-01 11:08:13 10037479    0401 UseRemote
10 2018-01-01 11:14:31 10037479    0301 UseRemote

structure(list(Time = structure(c(1514783675, 1514783688, 1514783693, 
1514783713, 1514783724, 1514783730, 1514783737, 1514785081, 1514785093, 
1514785471), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), CardID = c("10037479", 
"10037479", "10037479", "10037479", "10037479", "10037479", "10037479", 
"10037479", "10037479", "10037479"), Data = c("PowerOn", "0401", 
"0301", "0401", "0301", "1415", "0401", "1412", "0401", "0301"
), Type = c("STBEvent", "UseRemote", "UseRemote", "UseRemote", 
"UseRemote", "LiveView", "UseRemote", "LiveView", "UseRemote", 
"UseRemote")), .Names = c("Time", "CardID", "Data", "Type"), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am using lead and lag functions from dplyr to fetch data points before and after a particular row.  For example I am using this:

```
ae1 <- which(dplyr::lag(df$Data)=="1415")+1
```

This gets me row number 6 from the above data frame where the Type is equal to "LiveView".  I understand by altering the integer at the end of the code, I could get the respective line from the data frame. My question is:  can I use the same / similar function wherein I can fetch data the next "LiveView" - which is row number 8.  I can very well do

```
ae1 <- which(dplyr::lag(df$Data)=="1415")+3
```

to get row number 8.  But the next LiveView type can occur in any row other than 8.  I am thinking something similar to

```
ae1 <- which(dplyr::lag(df$Data)=="1415")+nrow(where Type == next "LiveView")
```

Comment: Your intended result is a little unclear. Assuming your data frame is named `df`, possibly something like `group_by(df, Type) %>% mutate(lag1 = lag(Data, 1))`. There is also the `lead` function, which moves in the opposite direction.

Comment: I agree with @jdobres. It's not clear what you're trying to do and how your expected output is supposed to look like. Could you please edit your question to include the expected output for the specific sample data you give?

Comment: Yes, this is not at all clear.  Please state the objective in words. Is it to obtain the row number?  row itself?  of the first LiveWire row past the first 1415 row?

Comment: "This gets me row number 6" -- nope, 8, when I run the code anyways.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** If the objective is to find the row number of the first `LiveWire` row past the first 1415 row then use the conjunction shown followed by `which` and `first` to get the row numbers and the first of those row numbers.  Note that `cummany` is true for the first `Data` component of 1415 onwards and by lagging it we get true only for those after it to the end.  If we knew that the there were only one such row then we could omit the `first`.  Since dplyr's lag conflicts with `lag` in the base we use `dplyr::lag` to be sure we are using the desired one.

```
df %>% 
  { dplyr::lag(cumany(.$Data == 1415)) & .$Type == "LiveView" } %>%
  which %>%
  first
  ## [1] 8
```

**2)** If we wanted the row itself instead then use `filter` and `slice`.  If we knew there were only one such row we could omit the `slice`:

```
df %>% 
  filter(dplyr::lag(cumany(Data == 1415)) & Type == "LiveView") %>%
  slice(1)
##                  Time   CardID Data     Type
## 1 2018-01-01 00:38:01 10037479 1412 LiveView
```

Note that if we added a row number to `df` by replacing the first line of code with:

```
df %>% mutate(n = 1:n()) %>%
```

then the above code would also give the row number in the `n` column in addition to the row itself in the other columns.

**2a)** An alternative to (2) is that we could first filter by `cumany(Data == 1415)` to give all rows from the first 1415 row onwards and then remove the first row since we only want rows *after* it and then find the `LiveView` rows within that and take the first.

```
df %>% 
  filter(cumany(Data == 1415)) %>%
  slice(-1) %>%
  filter(Type == "LiveView") %>%
  slice(1)
##                  Time   CardID Data     Type
## 1 2018-01-01 00:38:01 10037479 1412 LiveView
```

### Update

Revised.

Answer (score 1):

> I am using lead and lag functions from dplyr to fetch data points before and after a particular row. [...] can I use the same / similar function wherein I can fetch data the next "LiveView" [?]

If for each instance of Data == 1415, you want to find the next row where CardID matches, Type matches, and Time is greater, then there's...

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

mdf = df[Data == "1415", .(CardID, Type, Time)]
w   = df[mdf, on=.(CardID, Type, Time > Time), mult="first", which=TRUE]
df[w]

#                   Time   CardID Data     Type
# 1: 2018-01-01 00:38:01 10037479 1412 LiveView
```

If you have duplicate times, then `Time` won't work as a row number. You can add a row number like `df[, rn := .I]` or `df[, rn := rowid(CardID)]` and use that instead.

The line with `on=` is a non-equi join, currently not available in dplyr, which is why I'm posting with a different package here.

---

If you want to return both rows....

```
w0 = df[Data == "1415", which=TRUE]
w  = df[df[w0], on=.(CardID, Type, Time > Time), mult="first", which=TRUE]
df[matrix(c(w0, w), 2, byrow=TRUE)]

#                   Time   CardID Data     Type
# 1: 2018-01-01 00:15:30 10037479 1415 LiveView
# 2: 2018-01-01 00:38:01 10037479 1412 LiveView
```

Or if you also want data points before the row:

```
wb = df[df[w0], on=.(CardID, Type, Time < Time), mult="first", which=TRUE]
df[matrix(c(wb, w0, w), 3, byrow=TRUE)]

#                   Time   CardID Data     Type
# 1:                <NA>     <NA> <NA>     <NA>
# 2: 2018-01-01 00:15:30 10037479 1415 LiveView
# 3: 2018-01-01 00:38:01 10037479 1412 LiveView
```

NAs are shown since no row meets those criteria.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to `dplyr::group_by` the data based on `Type`, `dplyr::filter` the `Type` of interest, and then `dplyr::slice` to the position you want, in this case, position `2`:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- 
  structure(
    list(
      Time = 
        structure(c(1514783675, 1514783688, 1514783693, 
                    1514783713, 1514783724, 1514783730, 1514783737, 1514785081, 1514785093, 
                    1514785471), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
      CardID = c("10037479", "10037479", "10037479", "10037479", "10037479", "10037479", "10037479", 
                 "10037479", "10037479", "10037479"), 
      Data = c("PowerOn", "0401", "0301", "0401", "0301", "1415", "0401", "1412", "0401", "0301"), 
      Type = c("STBEvent", "UseRemote", "UseRemote", "UseRemote", 
               "UseRemote", "LiveView", "UseRemote", "LiveView", "UseRemote", 
               "UseRemote")), 
    .Names = c("Time", "CardID", "Data", "Type"), 
    row.names = c(NA, 10L), 
    class = "data.frame")


df %>% 
group_by(Type) %>% 
filter(Type %in% 'LiveView') %>% 
slice(2)
```